# Studying continuity of $f(x,y) = \left( \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2},\frac{e^{x^2+y^2}-1}{x^2 + y^2} \right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I need to study the continuity of this function:

> $$f(x,y) = \left( \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2},\frac{e^{x^2+y^2}-1}{x^2 + y^2} \right)$$

It's from an exercise of a calculus textbook. As they are continuous functions I know that the only problematic point is the origin... I know from previous exercises that the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ when $x$ approaches $0$ is $1$. But I don't know how to prove that the $y$ coordinate is algo going to $1$. Could you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the Taylor expansion for $e^{x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: I would'nt know how to do it... I'm just getting started with calculus

Comment: Are you aware of L'hospital's rule in 1D calculus? Composition of continuous functions?

Comment: @Sabyasachi that doesn't help here - it helps when you want to prove there is no limit but here there is

Comment: @Sabyasachi, that's not enough, for moving along a line doesn't prove if the limit exists.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht nevermind I brainfarted. Deleting my comments.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht is right, consider $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{y}$ where if you take $y=mx$ you get $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{mx} \to 0 $$ but if you take $y=x^2$ you get $1$, meaning there is no limit

Comment: Are Taylor expansions in general familiar to you? If not, how have you seen the identity $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use polar coordinates, your function's simply

$$f(r,\,\theta)=\left(\frac{\sin r^2}{r^2}\;,\;\;\frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2}\right)$$

Is it now clearer...?

Comment: I think OP is unfamiliar with $(e^x -1)/x$

Comment: @Sabyasachi That'd be very sad...and her/his problem. Someone messing around with two variables functions must, in my opinion, be well beyond those basic limits and functions...

Comment: Haha... okok now I'm a little bit sad, but I will dig more deeply into it with this ideas, thank you all

Comment: @GioacchinoScuticchio That's the spirit!+1 Anyway, observe that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x:=\left(e^x\right)'|_{x=0}\;\ldots$$